# I may have crossed wires on my dryer

Tags: dryer

I took the front panel off and the wires came undone from the door switch. I think i put them in the right way but im just not sure. Will it start if i mixed them up?

Comment: If there were just two wires, then you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

No worries, the switch is just a mechanical contact- closed or open. It doesn't matter. I won't tell you for sure it will start because you must have had some other problem or you would not have removed the front panel.